# Why aren't nodes of the last index over-represented in random networks generated with igraph?

Tags: c, r, igraph

I am using the R interface of `igraph` to generate a random directed network (Erdös-Rényi) with a constant number of nodes, `n`, and edges, `m`, using the function `sample_gnm`.

To make sure I understand which is the algorithm used, I checked the C source code although I have no experience in C.
As far as I understand the C code, there is an `if` statement that should lead to an over-representation of nodes with index `n` receiving directed edges.

This is the real code:
https://github.com/igraph/igraph/blob/7d4be976481356fa673772e6e7c30b637ea8dd52/src/games.c#L734-L736
and this is how I understand the C code in pseudo-code:

```
# What is the maximum number of edges a network with n nodes could have
maxEdges := n*(n-1)

s := uniformly sample m integers from [1, maxEdges] without replacement

for (i = 1; i = m; i++) {

  # Get IDs for nodes A and B with equal probability over n
  nodeA := floor(s[i] / (n)) + 1
  nodeB := s - ((nodeA - 1) * n)

  # Since we do not allow loops, if nodeA = nodeB, assign n to nodeB
  if (nodeA = nodeB) {
    nodeB := n
  }

}
```

However, I also run a simulation in R to make sure that this is really the case:

```
testFun = function(n,m) {

  # Generate the network
  g = sample_gnm(n, m, directed = TRUE, loops = FALSE)

  # Find the "to" node IDs
  toEdgename = ends(g, E(g))[, 2]

  return(toEdgename)

}

# Create 1000 random networks and get the "to" node name for each edge
spam = replicate(1000, testFun(100, 9000))
# Plot the histogram
hist(sapply(1:ncol(spam), 
            # Count the percent of times the index 100 appeared per simulation
            function(ii) sum(spam[, ii] == 100) / 9000), 
     100)
```

To my surprise, it does not lead to an observable bias.
This must mean that I do not comprehend what the C code is doing.
Could anyone please help me understand why does this piece of C code not lead to over-representation of the `n` index?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that `nodeB` in your pseudo-code can never be `n` (or, in the C code, it can never be `no_of_nodes - 1`. (However, `nodeA` *can* be `n`!)

In fact, the maximum value for `nodeB` is given by *maxEdges* (mod *n*−1), and values in mod *n*−1 are in the range [0, *n*−1[; note that the upper bound is exclusive.

Comment: So instead of sampling `nodeB` from all nodes excluding `nodeA`, it is sampled from all but the highest node. If `nodeB` equals `nodeA`, which can only happen for `nodeA != n`, the otherwise impossible node `n` is assigend to `nodeB`.

Comment: Thanks! 0-based indexing got me confused.